# Filter pandas dataframe if group size more than 1

Tags: pandas, dataframe, aggregate

Having the following DataFrame which is grouped:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'geonameid': ['1814991', '1814991', '3508796', '3508796', '3017382', '2017370', '2017370'], 
    'isolanguage': ['de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'de', 'de'],
    'alternate_name': ['China', 'Volksrepublik China', 'Dominikanische Republik', 'Dom. Republik', 'Frankreich', 'Russische Föderation', 'Russland'],
    'isPreferredName': ['', '', '1', '', '', '', '1'],
    'isShortName': ['1', '', '', '1', '', '', '']
})

grouped = df.groupby(['geonameid', 'isolanguage'])
```

How do I perform the following aggregation logic (having the same output structure):

1. Select only `isPrefferdName`, when there more than 1 value in the group.
2. Select first value if there's no such flag.
3. Not sure if possible to combine with #1, select `isShortName` if more than 1 value in the group.

How do I write any logic around the aggregation function?

```
df = df.groupby(['geonameid', 'isolanguage']).agg(
    { 'alternate_name': lambda series: list(series)[0] })
```

Preferred output: China, Dominikanische Republik, Frankreich, Russland.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC just `sort` on `isPrefferdName` and `isShortName`:

```
print (df.sort_values(["isPreferredName", "isShortName"], ascending=False)
         .groupby(['geonameid', 'isolanguage'])["alternate_name"].first())

geonameid  isolanguage
1814991    de                               China
2017370    de                            Russland
3017382    de                          Frankreich
3508796    de             Dominikanische Republik
```